# Issue with <select> tag in angular5

Tags: html, angular5

I am facing an issue with `<select>` tag in `angular 5`. I have an array of objects. Lets say

```
public countryList = [ {
    'name': 'xxx',
    'capital': 'abc'
  }, {
    'name': 'yyy',
    'capital': 'efg'
  }, {
    'name': 'zzz',
    'capital': 'pqr'
  },
];
```

and in `html`

```
    <select placeholder="Select" (change)="displayFunction()">
              <option class="auto-height" *ngFor="let country of countryList; let id=index"
                [disabled]="id === (country .length)-1" [value]="country .name">
                <div class="stop-container">
                    <b>{{country.name}}</b>
                    <p>{{country.capital}}</p>
               </div>
      </option>
```

The issue comes when we select any option in the dropdown all the values listed inside`<option>` is shown as the slected value. I need only `name` as selected value. Any solution for this? I am getting output given below. What is need is **XXX** instead of **XXX abc**

[image]

Comment: In options you want name + capital and when it is selected you want only name am i getting right?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a div inside your option. If you want to have some special formatting inside a dropdown you have to recreate the dropdown with JS (or use, for example, [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview))

So to only display the name, you can do the following:

```
<select placeholder="Select" (change)="displayFunction()">
      <option class="auto-height" *ngFor="let country of countryList; let id=index"
                [disabled]="id === (country .length)-1" [value]="country .name">
                {{country.name}}
      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there any example with angular material?

Comment: added a link to my post.

Comment: Thanks for that. But that does not meet my requirement

Answer (score -1):

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedDevice"  placeholder="Select" (change)="displayFunction($event.target.value)">
                  <option class="auto-height" *ngFor="let country of countryList; let id=index"
                    [disabled]="id === (country.length)-1" [value]="country.name">
                    <div class="stop-container">
                        <b>{{country.name}}</b>
                        <p *ngIf="selectedDevice!=country.name">{{country.capital}}</p>
                   </div>
          </option>
     </select>
```

Replace this line

Comment: you want to print name from select on change event  right ?

Comment: No. That I can do. But what I want to do is to display the selected name in the dropdown.

Comment: In the above attached image the selected value is shown as name + capital. I want only name